# hashcat benchmark not starting at all

Tags: hashcat

I'm trying to start hashcat on Win10 using my GPU AMD RX580.

What I did so far is:

1. Uninstalled all AMD drivers and rebooted
2. Started Driver Fusion cleaned all AMD Display drivers and rebooted
3. Manually removed OpenCL.dll from C:\windows\system32\ and c:\windows\syswow64 and rebooted
4. Installed AMD Crimsson driver edition - tried 17.8.2, 17.11.1, 17.11.4

My problem:

When I try to start a benchmark for WPA2 hash with `PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0> .\hashcat64.exe -m 2500 -b`

It starts and just quits without any output:

```
PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0> .\hashcat64.exe -m 2500 -b
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting in benchmark mode...

Benchmarking uses hand-optimized kernel code by default.
You can use it in your cracking session by setting the -O option.
Note: Using optimized kernel code limits the maximum supported password length.
To disable the optimized kernel code in benchmark mode, use the -w option.

* Device #2: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
OpenCL Platform #1: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
================================================
* Device #1: Ellesmere, 3264/4096 MB allocatable, 36MCU
* Device #2: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz, skipped.

Benchmark relevant options:
===========================
* --optimized-kernel-enable

Hashmode: 2500 - WPA-EAPOL-PBKDF2 (Iterations: 4096)

PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0>
```

Output from hashcat -I:

```
PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0> .\hashcat64.exe -I
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...

OpenCL Info:

Platform ID #1
  Vendor  : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Name    : AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Version : OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2442.8)

  Device ID #1
    Type           : GPU
    Vendor ID      : 1
    Vendor         : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
    Name           : Ellesmere
    Version        : OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2442.8)
    Processor(s)   : 36
    Clock          : 1366
    Memory         : 3264/4096 MB allocatable
    OpenCL Version : OpenCL C 2.0
    Driver Version : 2442.8

  Device ID #2
    Type           : CPU
    Vendor ID      : 128
    Vendor         : GenuineIntel
    Name           : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    Version        : OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2442.8)
    Processor(s)   : 8
    Clock          : 3599
    Memory         : 6131/24526 MB allocatable
    OpenCL Version : OpenCL C 1.2
    Driver Version : 2442.8 (sse2,avx)

PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0>
```

The same happens if I try to start mask attack.

Other benchmarks seems to work but when it reaches the WPA2 it just returns me to the command prompt:

```
PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0> .\hashcat64.exe -b
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting in benchmark mode...

Benchmarking uses hand-optimized kernel code by default.
You can use it in your cracking session by setting the -O option.
Note: Using optimized kernel code limits the maximum supported password length.
To disable the optimized kernel code in benchmark mode, use the -w option.

* Device #2: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
OpenCL Platform #1: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
================================================
* Device #1: Ellesmere, 3264/4096 MB allocatable, 36MCU
* Device #2: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz, skipped.

Benchmark relevant options:
===========================
* --optimized-kernel-enable

Hashmode: 0 - MD5

Speed.#1.........: 12381.1 MH/s (96.87ms) @ Accel:256 Loops:512 Thr:256 Vec:1

Hashmode: 100 - SHA1

Speed.#1.........:  4268.9 MH/s (70.02ms) @ Accel:256 Loops:128 Thr:256 Vec:1

Hashmode: 1400 - SHA2-256

Speed.#1.........:  1870.1 MH/s (80.00ms) @ Accel:256 Loops:64 Thr:256 Vec:1

Hashmode: 1700 - SHA2-512

Speed.#1.........:   461.1 MH/s (81.22ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:256 Vec:1

Hashmode: 2500 - WPA-EAPOL-PBKDF2 (Iterations: 4096)

PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0>
```

Any idea what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was a crash in the OpenCL runtime. I have installed the newest Adrenalin Drivers - 19.3.2 , but went into another issue :

```
PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0> .\hashcat64.exe -b -m 2500
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting in benchmark mode...

Benchmarking uses hand-optimized kernel code by default.
You can use it in your cracking session by setting the -O option.
Note: Using optimized kernel code limits the maximum supported password length.
To disable the optimized kernel code in benchmark mode, use the -w option.

OpenCL Platform #1: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
================================================
* Device #1: Ellesmere, 3264/4096 MB allocatable, 36MCU

Benchmark relevant options:
===========================
* --optimized-kernel-enable

Hashmode: 2500 - WPA-EAPOL-PBKDF2 (Iterations: 4096)

* Device #1: ATTENTION! OpenCL kernel self-test failed.

Your device driver installation is probably broken.
See also: https://hashcat.net/faq/wrongdriver

Speed.#1.........:   179.3 kH/s (87.14ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:64 Thr:256 Vec:1

Started: Mon Mar 18 19:05:55 2019
Stopped: Mon Mar 18 19:06:26 2019
PS D:\crack\hashcat-5.1.0>
```

Then I used the --self-test-disable option and it started . I have also created a post in the hashcat forum : https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-8226-post-44141.html#pid44141 in case anyone is interested .